# parameter in databricks sql analytics

Tags: parameter-passing, dropdown, databricks, databricks-sql

I have a table like

| name | value1 | value2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| john | a | x |
| kevin | b | y |
| larry | c | z |
|  |  |  |

I want to pass the parameter with dropdown values a,b,c,all where if user selects a then output is first row or if user selects all then also the out is all three rows.
Please suggest.

Answer (score 2):

You need to follow the [documentation on creating the parameters for Databricks SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/sql/user/queries/query-parameters#dropdown-list).  When editing the query, click on the `{}` icon to insert a new parameter into query, then select "Dropdown List" as a "Type", and enter possible values. Mark a checkbox "Allow multiple values" if you want to allow to select multiple values. And if you're using strings, timestamps, or dates, then select corresponding value from the "Quotation" dropdown:

[image]

and then modify your query to be something like (`actions` is the name of the parameter):

```sql
where action in ({{ actions }})
```

Then you can select necessary values from the dropdown:

[image]

and execution of the query should give you something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Solution in PySpark:

```
Choise_List = map(lambda x: str(x[0]), <Dataframe_Name>.select("value1").distinct().collect()) 
dbutils.widgets.dropdown("a", "a", Choice_List)
```

**Note:** Change the <Dataframe_Name> with your actual dataframe name.

Comment: Thanks. But I am looking for a sql in SQL Analytics in Databricks. Cant figure a way to do it.

Comment: plz try https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/notebooks/widgets#widgets-in-sql

Comment: this is for notebooks, not for SQLA